# Which is the best type of curve for these peaks on the waveform?

Tags: predictive-modeling, optimization

I have a waveform which looks like this. The peaks are indicated by the points. I want a type of curve fit which best connects these peaks as smoothly as possible.

[image]

I have tried polynomial fit but that does not yield a smooth curve. It looks something like this.
[image]

Here the green line is polynomial fit. As you can see it isn't as uniform as I want it to be. Also, poly fit **fails** to reach the max peak amplitude for some waveforms. So overall it is not what I am looking for. Is there a better fit that can account for these points better?

Comment: Try fitting to an exponential function.

Comment: I have tried. The problem being there are many kinds of waveforms which have to be accounted for and for some of them. Exponential fails. Even for this one